# Matlab Timer Function with output

Tags: matlab

does anyone know how to return output from the timer function, please?

I have tried to search online but it seems there is not a solution for it.

example code is :

```
function d=abc
         d=rand(3,1);
end

t=timer('TimerFcn',@(~,~)abc,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',5);
start(t)
```

Does anyone know how to save '`d`' as a variable, please ?

Comment: This is weird.... Why would you want to use the timer like that? can you describe what are you triying to achieve? the timer is that, a timer. A function that counts time. However, instead of counting time in seconds it will count it in `abc` executions. Are you triying to measure time?

Comment: The example i used here just for simple demonstration. The original purpose is to extract some data online every fixed time interval, but the matlab is not busy during this time interval.

Comment: No, if you use for or while loop, the matlab is busy and cannot do anything. But, the timer function can do it without occupy matlab. You can try t=timer('TimerFcn','disp(''hello'')','ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',10); start(t), you can do other work in Matlab and every 10 seconds you can see hello as well.

Comment: I see. What about the result `d`? there will be 5 `d`s. You want all of them?

Comment: Yes, 5 seconds  is just an example here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can solve this using objects? Define a class which holds your data:

```
classdef dataModel < handle
    properties
        step
    end
    methods
        function obj=dataModel()
            obj.step=0;
        end
        function incrementStep(obj)
            obj.step=obj.step+1
        end
    end
end
```

Then run it:

```
data=dataModel
t=timer('TimerFcn',@(~,~)data.incrementStep,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',5);
start(t)
```

You need some kind of reference where to put your data. Other possibilities are global variables or persistent variables.

Comment: We are becoming a bit hacky lately, aren't we?